# Why the status failed while creating a new connection?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL developer. When I am trying to create a new connection, I am getting the following error.

> "Status: Failure-Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

But, I am succeeded in creating new connection by editing the properties of the already existing connection.

Why it throws an error while trying the formal way?

Comment: Can you check if `tnsnames.ora` is complete and contains the database you want? Also check if the port if open from the server.

Comment: Yes "tnsnames.ora" contains my DB. Port is in open state.

Comment: Can you try to change the listner.ora file to `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))` and then try.

Comment: Actually, I am having only client access to DB. Can I change the listener.ora file and how?

Comment: With client access I am not sure if you can change it.

Comment: Is there any other way to change that? Or otherwise I will request DBA team to change it. May I know what is the need to change that?